# CRM 2015 Processes and choose workflow and Click Add step perform Action not appearing on the list

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I have created Action and Workflow through Process. I try to add the action into workflow but there is no  Perform action step displaying.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This feature is introduced in 2015 update 1. Verify if you have update 1 (not 0.1)

> With this version, now instead of creating a custom workflow assembly to invoke the action, we now have a new step available “Perform Action“.

[Reference](https://www.inogic.com/blog/2015/06/custom-actions-in-dynamics-crm-2015/)